# Should I keep "Write Caching" enabled on SSD drives?

Tags: windows-7, ssd, cache

Tweaking SSD drives for less wear seems to be all the rage nowadays.   On that subject is Write Caching still relevant on SSD drives? Does it make a difference if it is turned off?

Comment: Most advise to leave it on, since write caching is a function of the OS and main memory and not the hard drive itself...http://hardforum.com/showthread.php?t=1482813

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you aren't going to be hot-plugging drives, write caching should still speed things up, because writes are cached in main memory - SSDs are fast, but not as fast as RAM.

More information on how write caching works: http://www.pcguide.com/ref/hdd/op/cacheWrite-c.html